# populating a matrix with values that are a function of data from other matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have a question about working with matrices in R - please excuse me if any of it is clumsy or not clear - I am still an R beginner.

I have 2 matrices structured as follows:

An integer-valued organization to organization matrix indicating a valued relationship between organizations:

```
orgorg <- matrix(sample.int(50, 5*5, TRUE), 5, 5)
colnames(orgorg) <- colnames(orgorg, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "org")
rownames(orgorg) <- rownames(orgorg, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "org")
```

And a binary person to organization indicating which persons belong to which organizations:

```
personorg <- matrix(sample(0:1,10*5, replace=TRUE),10,5)
colnames(personorg) <- colnames(personorg, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "org")
rownames(personorg) <- rownames(personorg, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "per")
```

I have created a third person to person matrix as follows:

```
 npep=length(unique(rownames(personorg)))
 personperson <- matrix(0, npep, npep)
```

I would like to populate the elements of this matrix in the following way:

For each element in the personperson matrix [person i, person j], I would like to look up the organizations to which each person belongs (from the personorg matrix), and then fill in that element using the values in the orgorg matrix for those organizations.

So, for example, if person1 is a member of org2 and person2 is a member of org4, the element in the personperson matrix for [per1, per2] would be the element in the orgorg matrix for [org2, org4].

If an element [i,j] consists of persons who are members of multiple organizations, then I would like the element to be populated with the mean 'distance' between the organizations that the persons belong to. 
So, for example, if person 8 is a member of org2 and org4, and person 9 is a member of org 1, and

```
orgorg[org1, org2] = 12
orgorg[org1, org4] = 10
```

then

```
personperson[per8,per9] = 11
```

I hope this is clear! Thanks!

Comment: Could you also include `personperson`?

Comment: Actually `npep=length(unique(rownames(personperson)))` fails because  personperson is not defined.

Comment: What if a person belongs to multiple orgs (as your example suggests)?

Comment: good point thank you. In that case I'd like to have a function which takes mean 'distance' between the orgs that persons in a dyad belong to. I will add this into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is really interesting. I tried a solution making two new functions and finishing with a for loop. Please try this code and tell me if it works for you.

```
# Preamble
orgorg <- matrix(sample.int(50, 5*5, TRUE), 5, 5)
colnames(orgorg) <- colnames(orgorg, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "org")
rownames(orgorg) <- rownames(orgorg, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "org")

personorg <- matrix(sample(0:1,10*5, replace=TRUE),10,5)
colnames(personorg) <- colnames(personorg, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "org")
rownames(personorg) <- rownames(personorg, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "per")

npep=length(unique(rownames(personorg)))
personperson <- matrix(0, npep, npep)

rownames(personperson) <- rownames(personorg)
colnames(personperson) <- rownames(personorg)

# combine_custom function
combine_custom <- function(per1, per2, mat){
  one <- mat[per1,]
  one <- names(one)[one!=0]

  two <- mat[per2,]
  two <- names(two)[two!=0]

  if( (length(one) != 0 && length(one) == 1) | (length(two) != 0 && length(two) == 1) ){
    combinations <- combn(c(one, two), 2)
  } else {
    combinations <- matrix(0, 2, 1)
    for(i in 1:length(one)){
      combinations <- cbind(combinations, combn(c(one[i], two), 2))
    }
    combinations <- combinations[,-1]
  }

  combinations <- unique(combinations, MARGIN=2)
}


# ext function
ext <- function(x, mat){
  y <- mat[x[1],x[2]]
  y
}

# For loop
for(i in rownames(personperson)){
  for(j in colnames(personperson)){
    personperson[i,j] <- mean(apply(combine_custom(i, j, personorg), 2, function(x) ext(x=x, mat=orgorg)))
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply I'll review the code when I get a few moments!